# vim in FCEDIT=...vim... does not work with more than one option

Tags: command-line

When I write in a bash commamd line

```
vim -u /root/.vimrc -c "set textwidth=0"
```

this works as expected.

When using same in FCEDIT= it does not work:

```
FCEDIT='vim -u /root/.vimrc -c "set textwidth=0"'
```

The phrase "settextwidth=0" is taken as a filename.

Inclosing /root/.vimrc in any kind of quotes is no help.

I would not like to write a second version of .vimrc for this special case.

Do you have a solution?

Regards

Anton Wessel

Answer (score 1):

Here I can suggest two workarounds.

They are solutions to this task:

In FCEDIT to use vim with an option different from the settings in .vimrc.

E.g. I have in .vimrc set textwidth=66.
But when I write code for one-liners I need no limit on linelentgth, i.e. textwidth=0.

The first solution is simple in regard to the code, but it needs to steps.

To write the new option into a file:

echo "set textwidth=0">/tmp/WEx_vimrc

And to setup FCEDIT:

```
export FCEDIT='vim -u /root/.vimrc -S /tmp/WEx_vimrc'
```

The second solution has the advantage that all what has to be done is to type "fc":

```
alias fc="echo \"set textwidth=0\">/tmp/WEx_vimrc; export FCEDIT='vim -u /root/.vimrc -S /tmp/WEx_vimrc'; fc"
```

Regards

Anton Wessel

== addendum 21.12.2022

It is desirable to have both version of fc available:

1. the normal version fc which is determined when FCEDIT is setup,
2. this special FC with a different vim option.

This can be achieved when both are setup in a script.

For this now I add following IMPORTANT REMARK:

The order is important:

first must be setup

```
alias fc="echo \"set textwidth=0\">/tmp/WEx_vimrc; export FCEDIT='vim -u ~/.vimrc -S /tmp/WEx_vimrc'; fc"
```

and afterwards as second:

```
export FCEDIT='vim -u ~/.vimrc'
```

Regards